# Set the search index and the field_revision_body empty

Tags: database, search, nodes

I'm not using the core Drupal search engine and I'm not using any revisioning on my nodes.  I noticed that the `{search_index}` table and `{field_revision_body}` table are occupying 50Mo of my database space.

Does emptying these tables cause any problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't empty `field_revision_body` as it will break the content, but `search_index` is ok to empty.

Regarding search, please review the settings at: `/admin/config/search/settings`

e.g uncheck the Node and User search under "Active search modules"

Answer (score 2):

As @DavidThomas mentions, doing a `TRUNCATE` or `DELETE FROM` on the `{field_revision_body}` table will cause bad things to happen.  In short, your database will become inconsistent if everything related to a revision isn't deleted at the same time.  If you don't need old revisions, you may want to take a look at the [Node Revision Delete](http://drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete) module.  There are also [other questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=delete+old+revisions) here about deleting old revisions.

Clearing out both `{search_dataset}` and `{search_index}` is mostly fine.  If you look at the default profile for the Backup and Migrate module, you will see that the table structure (ie, the `CREATE` statements) is backed up, but the actual data isn't.  However, these tables will then continue to grow when cron runs, because `hook_update_index()` will get invoked, and modules that implement search will index things, unless you deactivate them as @DavidThomas mentioned.

If you don't actually need search, though, disabling and uninstalling the core Search module is probably the best bet, though.  Disabling the module will prevent the hooks from running, and uninstalling the module will remove all of the search tables from the database (the search module implements `hook_schema()`, so it manages its own tables, unlike some core tables that are handled by the system module).

Answer (score 0):

Of note, even if you use Apache Solr or another search module, core will continue to index into the search_index and search_dataset tables.

You can disable that with this in your settings.php

```
// Disable core search indexing
$conf['search_cron_limit'] = 0;
```